# is it possible to scroll containers which contains different components?

Tags: blackberry

is it possible to scroll containers which contains different components????

explain with a code please??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible:

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);      
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        vfm.add(new LabelField("lab" + i));
        vfm.add(new EditField("edit" + i,"val" + i));
    }           
    add(vfm);
```

Comment: you should accept answer if its good otherwise write comment why it's not good